# Why does git fetch do nothing?

Tags: git

On my local pc I've updated my file. Then I:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "text message"
git push
```

I can see the changes I made on Github.
Then I try to `git fetch` on my VM and it just says:

```
From github.com:mightyajax/scripts
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

but nothing happens? The file I need is still old version?

Maybe I'm donig it wrong I'm new to git and my idea is like I update a file on my local pc and fetch it on the VM. It's a pretty simple task I think and I don't understand the problem here.

git version is 2.37.1 os version is Ubuntu LTS and I'm using SSH key for Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) is working as intended - It fetches the current status of whatever is on the server (github).

The command you're looking for is [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). Pull will perform `git fetch` and then integrates the remote branch with your local branch and, if needed, either rebase or attempt a merge.

Comment: Yes thanks I didn't realize this! Thanks for answering